# Comparing 2 int arrays

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this method and why it gives a nullpointerException ?

```
public boolean check(){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] arr1 = new int []{1,2,3};
    int[] arr2 = new int[]{};

    for(int i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter numbers to check");
        arr2[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    if(arr1 == arr2)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: arr2 is initialized with no elements, meaning the length of the array is 0. Use int[] arr2 = new int[arr1.length] instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int[] arr1 = new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] arr2 = new int[arr1.length];
for (int i = 0 ; i < arr1.length ; i++) {
  System.out.println("Enter numbers to check");
  arr2[i] = scan.nextInt();
  if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 5):

You are not allocating enough memory for `arr2`. In this case, `arr2` is initialized with the length of 0.

Your 3rd line should be something like:

```
int[] arr2 = new int[arr1.length];
```

In addition, `if(arr1 == arr2)` is **not** the correct way to compare whether two arrays have the same elements.

Instead, you can use `java.util.Arrays.equals()` to check whether your two arrays are equal.

Answer (score 2):

you are not allocation any size for arr2 so it results in declaring its size to 0 in  which you input values finally resulting in null values....
and also you cannot compare array like you have done and even if you can one array being null wont give any result...........
try initializng arr2 with a size and den instead of doing (arr1==arr2)...try looping and finding the answer...will get you the answer.......
hope if helps....:)